# Why won't OS X Mountain Lion remember smb password on login?

Tags: macos, smb, login

After mounting an smb shared drive and putting in my username and password, OS X will ask me if I want to save password to keychain.  I can say yes but it will not save it.  The drive has also been added as a login item.

My username requires the domain, so it's like:
mydomain\firstname.lastname

On login, the window pops up and has forgotten the mydomain\ leaving firstname.lastname and the password field is, of course, blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try to save the password to the key-chain?

Comment: Also what did you add into the Login Items?

Comment: Nothing.  It logs in successfully but on next startup the window pops up again asking for password, username field is pre-populated with firstname.lastname.

For Login Items I click the plus and select the share from Devices in the Finder box that opens.

Thanks!

Comment: fuddyq have  look at the @hashchange answer, it totally solved my issue. It might be worth accepting it so that it goes to the top.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a link file with the username and password, and put that in the login items.

In Finder select Connect to Server and enter:

```
smb://domain\username:password@serveraddress
```

Don't click connect or press enter, just highlight the whole address and drag to desktop (or anywhere else), and it will save as a file. You can rename it, if you like.

Then from System Preferences, Users and Groups, Login items, add the file you just created.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and attempting to follow your directions.  Highlighting the address does not allow me to drag it to the desktop.  I attempted dragging favorites and this too does not work.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I can't seem to drag anything from the 'Connect to Server' window.

Answer (score 2):

Try making an alias of the network drive that you would like to connect to and store that in the Login Items.

1. Connect to the device / computer using the Finder. (Note don't connect as a guest)
2. Connect to the share or drive on that source, and open it using the Finder.
3. With that window open showing the contents of that connected share click the network share disk icon next to the window name, and drag it to the desktop while holding down the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd> keys.
   **Note:** *The icon just dragged to the desktop should have a tiny black arrow in the lower right corner, indicating that it is a alias.*
4. Add the Alias to your log in items.

**Note:** *If the problem persists, try removing the saved password for that share in the Keychain Access Application, and repeat.*

Comment: After tinkering with Keychain and logging in and out a dozen times, I think I'm ready to give up.  Thanks for your response MrDaniel.

No matter what I do it does not like the domain\ portion of the login and forgets it every time.  Strangely, even if I've removed it from login items the drive will still attempt to connect and fail.  But if I Finder > Go > Connect to Server and click it in the favourites, BAM, connected.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, and I have had it for ages. I eventually got rid of it by having a close look at the entries saved in the keychain - I actually found two relating to that server - and deleting them. (`Keychain Access` in `Programs` > `Utilities` is the tool for that.)

Once the botched entries were removed from the keychain, I could save my login credentials. Dragging the share to the sidebar in Finder, or to the desktop, also worked all of a sudden (it didn't previously).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a corrupt entry for that server in the Keychain. Delete the entry for that server from KeyChain Access, log out and back in, and try saving it again.